# Reattach return key

Tags: keyboard

I took off the key from my keyboard to get the worst of the muck out. My problem now is that I don't understand how to reattach the return key.
It has two metal bars: The small one stayed attached to the key when I removed it from the keyboard and seems unproblematic. But the long bar went lose and it is unclear to me where it goes.
You would think it should slide into the top, bottom and right (left from below) slits of the key, but when I try that, the key is really sticky and feels horrible to use. The best feeling I can achieve is with the small bar only, but it still feels worse than before I removed the key.

I attached some photos, does anyone know how this return key is to be reattached?
The images still look somewhat disgusting, sorry about that.)

[image: the key]
[image: the slot in the keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

Your keyboard (pictures a dead giveaway) is beyond practical redemption.

Please get a replacement keyboard and then you can easily move on.